# How to add a local Twig extension from a controller

Tags: symfony, filter, twig, local, twig-extension

I have a very specialized filter I want to use for a single page without making it a global filter. I tried doing this (that isn't the function I want, it's just a test):

```
$this->get('twig')
    ->addFilter(new \Twig_SimpleFilter('chgname', function ($string) {
        return substr($string, 0, 5);
    }));
```

But I get an error, "Unable to add filter as extensions have already been initialized".

I know that I can create a class in the AppBundle/Twig directory and add it as a service, but 1) That's incredibly heavy and a PITA for just a simple filter that I need, and 2) It makes it global to the entire application, which is dumb for something I need locally.

Is there any way to do this, or am I stuck with only global extensions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to do it locally, just use `substr()` in controller and pass result to twig.

Comment: He said that's not the function he wants.  I have to ask op though, what's wrong with using it globally for your bundle/app?  That's the proper way to do it, it's not heavy, and what does it matter if it's 'global' or not?

Comment: Why have local variables at all? Why not make them all global? Why not make all functions global? The answer is that it's bad practice to pollute your namespace with functions that don't need to be global. In this case, it's a very specific formatting function for one page that has no applicability anywhere else in the application. It's silly to make a simple one-shot a global function.

Comment: Function for only one page can be done in controller, I see no sense to make twig filter for that. Filters is for reusable use case.

Comment: Agreed with malcolm - if it's a one-off case just modify the data in your controller before passing it to your template.  Symfony advocates very light controllers and separation of concerns; there's really no way to do what you're looking for and I don't see how doing it the way Symfony suggests is introducing polluted global scope.

Comment: There's no logical or rational reason to insist that filters only be for "reusable" use cases, any more than functions in classes should only be for reusable use cases. Should we never have private functions? It's a silly restriction. And the whole point of this is to separate concerns: To move off this specialty filter to the controller where it belongs. And sure, I could modify the data before passing it to the template... but then, I could do all my modifications in the controller and never use filters for anything.

Comment: So just make that filter and don't ask questions to which you know the answer.

Comment: Well, I didn't know the answer, which is why I asked. I didn't really expect people to try and justify that globals are all anyone should need, though.

Answer (score 0):

Twig loads an environment when your app boots and you cannot dynamically change it.

if you think Symfony is too heavy you can still take a look at Silex (which uses Symfony components) so you could write something like :

```
$app['twig'] = $app->extend('twig', function ($twig) {
    $twig->addFilter(new \Twig_SimpleFilter('chgname', function ($string) {
        return substr($string, 0, 5);
    }));

    return $twig;
});
```

see http://silex.sensiolabs.org

Comment: Again the original poster stated that the `substr()` function isn't actually what he wants, it was just an example.

Comment: So he write example too! SO is not a quiz that we should  guess what function author mean.